# how to auto scale spark job in kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, autoscaling

Need an advice on running spark/kubernetes. I have Spark 2.3.0 which comes with native kubernetes support. I am trying to run the spark job using spark-submit with parameters master as"kubernetes-apiserver:port" & other required parameters like spark image and others [as mentioned here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html) .
    How to enable auto scaling / increase the no of worker nodes based on load? Is there a sample document I can follow ? Some basic example/document would be very helpful. 
     Or is there any other way to deploy the spark on kubernetes which can help me achieve auto scale based on load.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Apache Spark 2.3.0 does not officially support auto scalling on K8S cluster, as you can see in [future work after 2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/running-on-kubernetes.html#future-work).

BTW, it's still a feature working in progress, but you can try on the k8s fork for Spark 2.2